# Can not build ngtoast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtoast

I'm just trying to run [ngtoast](https://github.com/karaxuna/ngtoast), I recently  came across, but it gives me an error

> no such file or directory 'c:\modules'

I'm trying to run ngtoast like this:

```
 ngtoast build
```

what am I doing wrong?
Here is my config file:

```
{ 
    "public": "./public", 
    "modules": "/modules", 
    "output": "./public/modules.js" 
}
```

Comment: please show us how does your ngtoast.json file look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in configuration file. `modules` parameter is RELATIVE url from `public` folder ([see documentation](https://github.com/karaxuna/ngtoast#config)). So it must be `"modules": "./modules"` instead of `"modules": "/modules"`